# What's equivalent of the groovy gradle JNI configuration in kotlin gradle script?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, java-native-interface, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm having hard time converting the following groovy script to a kotlin script (build.gradle -> build.gradle.kts).

```
model {
    components {
        main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
               // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the docs I found [Build native software](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html), [Setup JNI development in Gradle project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-up-jni-development-in-gradle-project.html) all have groovy syntax, but none of them have kotlin syntax. Tried finding on other OS projects but found nothing.

I was trying to find some of the type info to get some clue:
[image]

And trying out the stuff in kts:

```kotlin
val model by tasks.getting(ModelReport::class) {
    components {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But seems like there's no property called components in that object.
[image]

Basically can't figure out anything on my own now, if somebody can help it will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old native plugin that you try to use (`c`) usees the rule-based software model.
Those plugins are (or will be) deprecated and instead the replacements like `cpp-library` should be used.

The tutorial link you posted also has a link to an  example of how to use the replacement plugins in Groovy DSL that you should be able to port to Kotlin DSL easily.

Besides that, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html states in the section "Limitations":

> The Kotlin DSL will not support the `model {}` block, which is part of the [discontinued Gradle Software Model](https://blog.gradle.org/state-and-future-of-the-gradle-software-model). However, you can apply model rules from scripts — see the [model rules](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/tree/master/samples/model-rules) sample for more information.